# How to modrewrite in my subfolder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a PHP script on a subfolder of my server and it generates url like this:

```
http://example.com/subfolder//index.php?a=profile&u=username
```

Instead I would like a SEO friendly url like:

```
http://example.com/subfolder/profile/username.html
```

I'm on Apache and mod_rewrite is enabled, so I edited the `.htaccess` of my subfolder page:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ //index.php?a=$1&u=$2 [L]
```

But it doesn't work.
This is my full `.htaccess` code:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{request_filename} -f
RewriteRule ^(.*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(([^/]*)+)(/([^/]{0,32})(/.+)?)?$  index.php?a=$1&q=$3    [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)\.html$ //index.php?a=$1&u=$2 [L]
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this rule in `/subfolder/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /subfolder/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)\.html$ index.php?a=$1&u=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: thanks, I make a mistake in the second line of code...I need to keep the `/subfolder/` in the url. I updated the question

Comment: oh ok in that case modified answer will work in `/subfolder/.htaccess`